# TensorFlow: Does changing hyperparameters like dropout probability increase GPU memory needed to train?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

After changing some hyperparameters like dropout and weight decay, I found that my batch_size has to be reduced constantly in order to fit the training, even with an 11GB memory Tesla K80. I used to train with batch size 32, but now even a batch size 24 will cause a resource exhausted error after changing my hyperparameters. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case in which changing the hyperparameters can change the network size is when the hyperparameters values can enable/disable a layer.

For instance, if you set the `keep_prob` dropout hyperparameter to `1`, the layer itself is not created but the input is returned.

The same can happen for the weight decay: if the weight decay penalty is equal to `0` then the decay terms to the loss function are not added.

In any other case (for instance for `keep_prob` in `]0, 1[`) the layer is added and its size is constant.

The problem should be somewhere else in your graph definition, probably.

Comment: I have found out the issue, which is simply my hard disk ran out of space. I didn't realize this obvious mistake as I was running on AWS and upon clearing the unneeded libraries, the original batch_size 32 worked. Thank you for your interesting insight on how the hyperparameters affect the computations.